# Incorrect measurements when using "Create Grid" tool in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, vector-grid, units

I am using the "Create Grid" tool in QGIS to simply create a 25x150ft grid. I am using EPSG:3857. When I select my parameter I want and run the tool, I double-checked the dimensions with the measurement tool and found that the grid dimensions were different from what I originally set.

For time sake, I ended up just guessing and checking until I got the grid in the proper dimensions, but would like to know how to fix this for the next time it happens. I noticed that if I switched the measurement tool into Cartesian, then the dimensions are correct.

Do I need to switch all my layers into a Cartesian format, create grid, and reproject back?

That would seem a bit ridiculous especially if I had to project the rasters I am working with (<10GB).

**Create Grid**
[image]

**Vertical Dimension Ellipsoidal**
[image]

**Vertical Dimension Cartesian**
[image]

Comment: Please do **not** ever use EPSG:3857 (Web Mercator) to carry out any sort of distance related analysis. The longitude (X) axis is distorted to infinity as you move north or south of the Equator.

Comment: Interesting, yeah I just switched to EPSG: 32610 and the Ellipsoidal dimensions were dead on. Thanks for the knowledge. I will need to read more into this! Could you please post an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: It's actually the latitude (Y) that's distorted to infinity, and this is a common topic (3-5 times/week).

Comment: @Vince, I was wondering about *"(3-5 times/week)"*. What does it actually mean?

Comment: Well, questions related to using Web Mercator for distance don't occur every day, but they are quite frequent (and therefore don't require full-on Answers in each Question). At some point we'll have to close all these as duplicates of some canonical "I'm trying to use EPSG:3857 for distance measurements but getting wrong measuremens" Question, but the task is daunting.

Comment: @Vince, I see what you meant. Thank you for clarity! I fully agree with your point!